# Disabling animations does not allow to run Espresso tests correctly

Tags: android, android-espresso

When using Espresso for Android testing it is recommended to disable three options related to animations. It is assumed that by doing this we will prevent main thread from drawing the animations, the thread will become idle when we expect him to be and the test will not stall on lines like:

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

But the evil truth is that it doesn't work!

I set `window animation scale`, `transition animation scale` and `animator duration scale` to `off` in developer options of my device. Then I run my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExchangeRatesActivityTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<ExchangeRatesActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        ExchangeRatesActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void test() {

    onView(withId(R.id.amountEditText))
            .perform(typeText("100"));

    onView(withId(R.id.progressBar))
            .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));

    onView(withId(R.id.convertButton))
            .perform(click());
  }
}
```

After the last `.perform(click())` the test suspends for a while after which I get this:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 719, 735 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.sample.app:id/convertButton'.
```

Some more facts:

- When I turn off those options the progress bar doesn't appear.
- When I inspect the app with CPU Android monitor after clicking the button, the app spends clocks on drawing the progress bar even though it cannot be seen.
- I tried that on two different phones so it's not hardware dependent.

Comment: I meant that I turned those options off in developer options, manually. I didn't write any code to do that.
That's the problem: the suggested way doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the full stack-trace? I think it must be some crucial piece of information in the midle of this stack-trace explaining why the action can not be performed. For example, it might be something overlapping the element.

Comment: add full-stac trace with log error. Check your code. Are you sure that after data load you're removing progressbar view?